# Flixel Development in Ubuntu/Linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, flixel

I've been trying to setup a development environment for Flixel on Ubuntu using this guide http://forums.flixel.org/index.php?topic=4545.0 but thus far have been unsuccessful mainly due to the guide being dated and using an outdated and inactive plugin for Eclipse (axdt).

I was wondering if anyone currently develops Flixel based games using Ubuntu/Linux, and if so how you got yourself setup. Ideally I would want to use an IDE like Eclipse but I would be open to other options.

Comment: Have you tried just writing your code in a plain old text editor and compiling with mxmlc at the command line?

Comment: I have not, but I will give that a try tonight.

Comment: Double check your compile flags. There's some weirdness where you may not be statically linking something you should be.

Comment: Yeah. I was able to compile a Flixel project with mxmlc. Had to set static-link-runtime-shared-libraries to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can successfully compile a Flixel project on Ubuntu by downloading the [Flex SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex-sdk-download.html), adding it to your PATH, and running `mxmlc YourMainGameFile.as -static-link-runtime-shared-libraries=true`

OR

Install Eclipse 3.7 Indigo, FDT 5 (http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/fdt-1#.UPolm32Ux0w), and the Flex SDK mentioned above. Make a new Flash Web project and setup a run config.